# Dealing with different word order in a multi-language application?

Tags: translation, language, translation-workbench

I am developing a multi-language application which supports English and Japanese. But, as everyone might have known, the language structure of these two languages are quite different. For example, when I want to show "Line 1" on a VF page in Japanese, it'd be "1行目"(meaning the first line).

I created a custom label named 'Line'.

Japanese = 行目 and English = Line.

I'm planning to develop the process mentioned above as follows;
(The code might not compile. It's just a concept.)

```
String showString;
String number = '1';
if(UserInfo.getLanguage() =='ja') showString = number + Label.line;
else showString = Lable.line + number;
```

But I don't want to put an if in my code for every language.

Is there any better ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where `String.format` comes in play. For example, you could write this:

```
String errorLine = String.format(Label.error_on_line_x, new string[] { String.valueof(linenumber) });
```

This way, label might be 'Error on line {0}' in English, and '{0}行目' in Japanese, and it will format correctly in both languages (use the label translation system...).

Comment: Thank you. I just did as you suggested and it works. This is very helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

What I would do in this case is create a set of languages that have the number before the label:

`Set <String> languagesWithLabelAsSuffix = new Set <String> {'ja', 'XX', 'YY'};`

and then check if the user language is one of the above:

```
String showString;
String number = '1';
if (languagesWithLabelAsSuffix.contains(UserInfo.getLanguage()) == true)
{
    showString = number + Label.line;
}
else
{
    showString = Lable.line + number;
}
```

Also, for easier maintainability, you can create custom settings where you can store semi-colon separated language initials for those languages, parse that string and store the values in the `languagesWithLabelAsSuffix` set.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! This is better than my approach. I have never used custom settings before. I'll learn more about it. Must be useful for the future. :]

Comment: -1 This idea is exceedingly limiting - the developer must know all the kinks of the languages he must support.  Instead of trying to turn the developer into a linguist, let the translator do this as in @sfdcfox's [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/42529)